# Multiple app versions from different developer accounts

Tags: ios, ios-appstore, developer-program

Can I submit the same app from multiple developer accounts with just different app icon and some color difference inside the app?

Comment: I'd love to know ***why?***

Comment: Each customer want to sell the same app under its own brand

Comment: Ah, OK - makes more sense than just the question on its own - thanks :) ...though that might be part of your submission, that it needs different branding for a specific purpose.

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to do this but without a clear and compelling reasons Apple might reject later editions.

Acceptable reasons might include differing legal ownership for different geographic regions.

From Apple's [App Store Review Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/):

> ## App Store Review Guidelines
>
> ### 2. Functionality
>
> 2.11 Apps that duplicate Apps already in the App Store may be rejected, particularly if there are many of them, such as fart, burp, flashlight, and Kama Sutra Apps

Comment: Yep I know this paragraph, but I think it applies to 100 apps not to 10 or sth like this, what is your opinion?

Comment: My opinion does not matter. Submit your applications to Apple and see what Apple's reviewers think. Good luck!